# Named Query with map values in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, jpa-2.1

i have a hashmap like which has key value pair such as :

```
testMap = new HashMap(){{
                        put(iD, sID);
                        put(lEVEL, sLevel);
                        put(tYPE, sType);
                        put(vALUE, sValue);
```

Now i have my entity Class which has fields like

```
@Column(name = "ID")
private String id;

@Column(name = "LEVEL")
private String level;

 
@Column(name = "PROGRAM")
private String program;

   
@Column(name = "TYPE")
private String type;

  
@Column(name = "VALUE")
private String value;

@Column(name = "STARTDATE")
private Date start;
```

Now i need to form a named query where for each column i have to set values by extracting them from map key value pair (something like this :tesMap.get(iD) and setting in ID column) and also comparing the start date with the current date and setting the largest date in startdate column .
Tried the following using Named query but didn't work .

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM OVERRIDES s " +
            "WHERE s.ID =?1 AND s.LEVEL=?2 AND s.TYPE=?3 AND s.VALUE=?4", nativeQuery = true)
```

Also ,unable to decide how to compare dates in this select query .

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the dates can be easily done with `Date.after()` method.

E.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("2022-07-01");
Date date2 = sdf.parse("2022-08-31");

if(date1.after(date2)) {
    //set largest date in date column
}
```

As for the rest question, please provide the whole Entity, or maybe more infos about the query

Comment: Thanks @mikopos ,i have added the entity class above and wanted to know how to perform these functions using jpa /@Query or criteria api

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can compare dates/timestamps with relational operators `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=` i.e.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM OVERRIDES s " +
        "WHERE s.ID =?1 AND s.LEVEL=?2 AND s.TYPE=?3 AND s.VALUE>=?4", nativeQuery = true)
```